# Libreoffice in command line mode: Multiline cells are lost during Excel conversion to pdf

Tags: excel, pdf, libreoffice

I'm trying to convert an Excel file that contains multiline cells to PDF. The cells are all on one line in the generated PDF.

Here is the command I use :

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export "test.xlsx" --outdir "tmp/"
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Is this an actual excel file, or the libreoffice equivalent of excel?

Comment: This is an actual excel file.

Comment: @pnorton that is something that is discouraged, as you never know what a file actually contains. It would be helpful to share the content of a violating cell for example.